# Easy problem of combinatory help with the solution

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine we have a bakery, they open

- In the morning from $07$ a.m to $14$ p.m
- In the afternoon they work from $14$ h to $21$ hours

and there are four workers $A, B ,C ,D$.

In the morning they will work in couples ($2$ people in the bakery) in the afternoon they will work alone. Then is there a possible solution so all the $4$ people work $35$ hours a week, they have the Sunday afternoon 'free' (bakery closed) and a free day at a week.

Answer (score 1):

I would write ABCD repeat 5 :ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD

Then I would add separators : AB|C||DA|B||CD|A||BC|D||AB|C||DA|B||CD

And I would check if it is ok.